# How to use SPARQL endpoint in fuseki with HTTP in the browser

Tags: database, http, sparql, endpoint

I would like to use my fuseki endpoint `http://localhost:3030/ds/query` in my browser, I tried something like this: `http://localhost:3030/ds/query=myQuery` but I got the error:

```
Error 404: Not found: dataset='ds' service='query=SELECT+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%0AWHERE+%7B%0A++%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%0A%7D%0ALIMIT+25'
```

'ds' is the default dataset in my fuseki server.

How do I use the endpoints with HTTP in the borwser? I have only see examples with curl

Comment: How do you start Fuseki?

Comment: like this: ./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds

Comment: You're missing the common HTTP param. Up to here `http://localhost:3030/ds/query` it is just the service, now you have to define the query param, i.e. `http://localhost:3030/ds/query?query=myQuery` It might sound confusing, but imagine that you change it to `http://localhost:3030/ds/sparql` in a config file, then it becomes more obvious

Comment: Thanks, fixed my problem!

Comment: or `/ds?query=` (recent versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by AKSWs and AndyS' comments. to define the query param i use the '?' character.

Like this: `http://localhost:3030/ds/query?query=myQuery` 
or this: `http://localhost:3030/ds?query=myQuery`